# return elements from List considering an alphabet rule

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

So I'm trying to build a function that receives as a parameter a List of 5 elements, this list is of the string type, and the result that I'm after follows this logic:

List:

```
List<string> lista= new List<string>();

            lista.Add("Movel");
            lista.Add("ONU");
            lista.Add("Pata");
            lista.Add("Tela");
            lista.Add("Plasticos");
```

I need to return only the elements where the last letter is superior to the first following alphabetical order, in this case, only "ONU" and "Plasticos" would be returned.

I'm rather new to C#, in fact, I'm just new to programming overall, but in the small knowledge I've accumulated, I honestly don't know where to go with this, any help would be grand.

Answer (score 1):

Theres probably regex ways you can do this or something, but you can probably do this with a Linq expression of some sort e.g.

```
IEnumerable<string> temp = from str in lista
                       let last = str.ToLower().Last()
                       let first = str.ToLower().First()
                       where last > first
                       select str;
```

Would give you the answers you seek I think, but that's probably a pretty inefficient way to do it if you need a quick algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
return lista.Where(s => { s = s.ToLower(); return s[0] < s[s.Length-1] });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List<string> listb = lista.FindAll(s => String.Compare(s.Substring(s.Length - 1), s.Substring(0, 1)) == 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I could come up with this

```
List<string> filtered = lista.FindAll(s => char.ToLowerInvariant(s[s.Length - 1]) > char.ToLowerInvariant(s[0])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

My result:

```
var result = lista.Where(x => x.ToLower()[0] < x.ToLower()[x.Length - 1]).ToList();
```